# JSON rendering with activemodel serializer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I just wonder how the rails render the model objects with activemodel-serializer in JSON.
I installed activemodel-serializer but the output is something different.

The ideal is something like:

```
"products": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Digital Portable System",

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Plasma TV",
  }

]
```

However what I got so far is;
[image]

My code is simple;

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Product.all  
  end

  def show
    respond_with Product.find(params[:id])   
  end

  def create
    product = current_user.products.build(product_params) 
    if product.save
      render json: product, status: 201, location: [:api, product] 
    else
      render json: { errors: product.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def update
    product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    if product.update(product_params)
      render json: product, status: 200, location: [:api, product] 
    else
      render json: { errors: product.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def destroy
    product = current_user.products.find(params[:id]) 
    product.destroy
    head 204
  end

  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :published) 
    end

end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Product Controller

```
def index
   render json: Product.all, each_serializer: ProductsSerializer, root: false
end
```

#### Product Serializer - `app/serializers/products_serializer.rb`

```
class ProductsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title

end
```

Comment: What is the `root: false` for?

Comment: @Francois , it gives root name in default, smth like if product table `{products: [...]}` that products is root name. But on version `<0.10.x` root doesnt work i think. `root: false` just removes, the products key name and keeps it `{[...]}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def index
   render json: Product.all, only: [:id, :title]
end
```