# ActiveModelSerializer only showing id for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to using an ActiveModelSerializer in my API. Everything seems to work except for the BusinessCategory relationship. It just shows the id for that. I want it to show all the attributes. I'm not sure it's even using the serializer because when I remove the relationship it still shows up.

#### PerksSerializer

```
class PerksSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :status, :scope, :business_name, :business_description, :business_address_street,
    :business_address_state, :business_address_city, :business_address_postal_code,
    :business_website, :latitude, :longitude, :headline, :description, :start_date, :end_date,
    :redemption_instructions, :cashier_instructions, :redemption_button_text, :claim_type,
    :business_manager_approved_by, :created_at

  belongs_to :primary_business_category

  belongs_to :secondary_business_category
end
```

#### PerksController

```
  def index
    data = property.available_perks
    render json: data
  end
```

#### BusinessCategorySerializer

```
class BusinessCategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :description
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835437/json-rendering-with-activemodel-serializer-in-rails/40835702#40835702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same code like:

```
class PerksSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :status, :scope, :business_name, :business_description, :business_address_street,
    :business_address_state, :business_address_city, :business_address_postal_code,
    :business_website, :latitude, :longitude, :headline, :description, :start_date, :end_date,
    :redemption_instructions, :cashier_instructions, :redemption_button_text, :claim_type,
    :business_manager_approved_by, :created_at, :primary_business_category,:secondary_business_category


   def primary_business_category
     BusinessCategorySerializer.new(object.primary_business_category)
   end

   def secondary_business_category
     BusinessCategorySerializer.new(object.secondary_business_category)
   end
end
```

or

```
belongs_to :primary_business_category, serializer: BusinessCategorySerializer

belongs_to :secondary_business_category, serializer: BusinessCategorySerializer
```

Check if your PerksSerializer is called, if not:

```
 def index
   data = property.available_perks
   render json: data, each_serializer: PerksSerializer
 end
```

Comment: I've tried both. I think that the problem is the serializer is not being used at all. No matter what changes I make the output is the same.

Comment: But your PerksSerializer is called?

Comment: `each_serializer: PerksSerializer` did it. Thanks