# Active Model Serializer doesnt use JSON:API adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I am using ActiveModelSerializers gem and I want to use JSON:API format, so I added to config line:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

In controllers where I use serializers JSONs are in JSON:API format, but unfortunately when I want to create json using serializer object for example:

```
Serializer.new(Model.first).to_json
```

in my specs or rails console it uses default JSON format, not JSON:API

Comment: Which AMS version are you using?

Comment: 0.10.8 version.

Comment: check with this: `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Model.first).as_json`

Comment: @Ni3 your method works, but is it really the best way to do this?

Comment: plz check this: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable

Comment: But what if I have many serializers for one model and want to use the one with incompatible name?

Comment: @WuJo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835437/json-rendering-with-activemodel-serializer-in-rails/40835702#40835702

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Json Api version of your serialized object, you need to call `as_json` on the Adapter wrapped object

```
# serializer object
serializer = Serializer.new(Model.first)
# wrap it in the adapter and call as_json or to_json
ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer).as_json
```

Comment: "Try..." is debugging comment, not an answer. Please add some explanation